# Create install package of current pip packages (similar to pip freeze)

Tags: python, pip

I'm needing to create an install package which contains all of the pip packages currently installed. Generally I think of this as using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. However since I'm needing the actual install package I then need to do `pip download -r requirements.txt`.

It seems strange to have to download the packages if they are already on my computer opposed to being able to package them up. This also creates an install `.whl` for each package opposed to a single one. (This is not a show-stopper)

What is the best method for generating an install package of the current environment for pip packages?

Comment: I believe `pip install -r requirements.txt` is what you're looking for

Comment: Per our requirements we must maintain copies of all the software we use (e.g. the `.whl` files from `pip download`). Unfortunately just maintaining a `requirements.txt` file is not enough for us.